Constructing position vector
I am a student from a non-English speaking country. And I recently took a linear algebra class and heard about position vectors. Here, I started to have questions about the process of constructing position vectors. Since this is a linear algebra class in a non-English speaking area, it would be difficult to fully convey the class content, so I will briefly summarize the content.


(I saw this picture in here) In this picture, we can see that vector $a$ and vector $b$ are equal to each other. How do we know that? We say that vector $a$ and vector $b$ are equal if when vector $a$ is translated parallel to vector $b$, they overlap each other, and this is written as $a=b$.
And, since there are numerous vectors on the coordinate plane and it is difficult to express them one by one, let's define it as follows:
$$S:= \text{all vectors set in} \Bbb R^2$$
And by choosing elements $v_1$ and $v_2$ in $S$, we can think of the equivalence relation as follows. $$v_1\sim v_2\iff v_1=v_2$$
Now, let's think the other way around and consider the representative of the quotient set $S/ \sim$, which is the set of all unequal vectors in $S$.
Now, let us take any element in $S$ and choose a representative in its equivalence class as follows: Set the starting points of all vectors on a coordinate plane to start from the origin.(=position vector)

As far as I understand, the explanation is like this. However, I don't quite understand this explanation, so I googled it, but I couldn't find a similar article, so I wonder if I misunderstood it. So I want to know in detail how the process of creating a position vector is done in linear algebra.

We typically refer to these as free vectors. Two free vectors $\overrightarrow{AB}$ and  $\overrightarrow{CD}$ are equivalent if, when we parallel translate the second so that the tails coincide, the heads coincide as well. This is equivalent to the algebraic condition that (for any coordinate system) $B-A=D-C$.

Making (translating) the tail, $A$, of $\overrightarrow{AB}$ the origin gives what they call the position vector $B-A$.

@TedShifrin Hi, thanks for the comment. I learned about the detailed definition of position vector.

Perhaps I should enter this as the official answer if you’re satisfied.

@TedShifrin Is the position vector a mathematical object formed as you wrote, not as I wrote in my question?

These are the same. The vector $\overrightarrow{AB}$ is equivalent to a unique vector with its tail (starting point) at the origin — namely the one whose head (ending point) is at $B-A$, as I said.
